# Problems with Zend_Lucene when using Routes

Tags: zend-framework, zend-lucene

I have implemented Zend_Lucene in my first Zend Framework Project, but since I have implemented Routes the Search Results does not seem to work anymore.

In my Search Result view, I have changed the URL to the Postdetails to use the Route:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('post' => $value['post_id'], 'postname' => $value['post_title']), 'postdetails', true); ?>">
```

Unfortunately it does not seem to work, instead it shows me

```
<a href="/%3C%21DOCTYPE+html+PUBLIC+.......
```

I normally also use

```
$this->escape($value['post_title'])
```

but again, it shows something with DOCTYPE. I don't understand enough about ZF to know what goes wrong. Can someone give me a hint? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your named route without setting the reset option to true? I think you might be contradicting your self. You are telling the url helper to use a named route at the same time telling it to use the default routes. if you haven't already try:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('post' => $value['post_id'], 'postname' => $value['post_title']), 'postdetails'); ?>">
```

you also may need to set default values for `post` and `postname` in your route(if you haven't already)

Comment: I tried it out but still does not work. I understood the reset option anyway in a different way, but might be wrong. 
Looking in the Code it says about reset... "Whether or not to reset the route defaults with those provided"

When I want to use a URL without any routes, than I have to enter 'default' as a Routename, instead in my case 'postdetails' 

Correct me if I am wrong on this. Any other ideas what I could try out?

Comment: @Luka what is actually in your $value array? Also post your route definition.

Comment: I found the reason for the Problem. In my Action where I read out the Index, I had the following part $query->highlightMatches($result->postTitle); highlightMatches caused the issue, since this is creating some HTML. That took me 5 days to figure this out :(